# Selenium handle dropdown suggestions as i send text input?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

consider this simple html.

```
<div role="label">
<label>Names</label>
</div>
<div role="input">
<input type="names">
</div>
```

I have my code like this

```
WebElement input= "inputXpathString";
input.sendKeys("Sam Winchester")
```

This sends the correct name, however as the name is being sent to the input box, a dropdown shows showing the name. How do i handle the dropdown?
I tried `input.sendKeys(Down, Return)` it doesn't work. I also tried, clicking anywhere on the page, that doesn't help either.

What else can I do?

Comment: Maybe try send keys enter. Also what site is it.

Comment: I already tried `input.sendKeys(Down, Return)` can't  share the website. its internal.

Comment: How is the dropdown implemented? Try clicking using input.click().

Comment: sounds like this is the browser's own control.  (auto-suggest)  This is not a part of the DOM, so Selenium doesn't have access to it.  (Nor do other websites, which is a good thing.  This keeps the "sandbox" intact.)  Send keys might work... not real sure... seems like something they would prevent, but you could try input.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) and input.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)  If the website implements their own auto-suggest, it would be in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code using JavascriptExecutor interface:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
//casting a driver instance into JavascriptExecutor instance
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
//set the dropdown value to 'Sam Winchester' using javascript
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='Sam Winchester'", input);
```